# Trouble installing Django 2.x in Ubuntu 18

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, pip

I am trying to install the latest `Django` in `Ubuntu 18`, But I am facing some weird troubles. I came across 2 ways to install it.

**Method 1**: If I use below command then the previous version of `Django` is getting installed

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-django
$ django-admin --version
1.11.11
```

**Method 2**: If I install it using `pip` then on checking the version I see an error as it's not installed though I can remove it successfully

```
$ pip3 install Django==2.1.2
$ django-admin --version
Cannot find installed version of python-django or python3-django.
```

Can anybody help me It's very frustrating, ThankYou

Comment: `pip3 install Django` should do it. Does it gives any error?

Comment: yeah I support @VaibhavVishal you should also insall it in venv so if you mess something wont mess your system

Comment: @VaibhavVishal Thank you it worked can you make an answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this in terminal to install latest stable version of Django:

```
pip3 install Django
```

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/install/#install-django)